# Link for list item doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to create a link on this list item. Why is this method not working?

```
#jQuery(function(){     
var theList = jQuery('#someList'); 
var content = jQuery('<a href="Settings"><li id="content'+i+'"></li><a/>' 
theList.append(content);
```

Comment: Your `<a>` and `<li>` tags are back to front for starters! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing parentheses from your code, try this?

```
var theList = $('#someList'),
    i = 0, // i isn't defined in the code you displayed, is it in a loop by chance?
    content = '<li id="content' + i + '"><a href="Settings">Put Something Here</a></li>';
theList.append(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to refresh the list:

```
theList.append(content).listview('refresh');
```

UPDATE: Your Code

```
jQuery(function(){ 
    var theList = jQuery('#someList'); 

    for(i=0; i < mytool_array.length; i++) { 
        content = '<li id="content'+i+'"><a href="dgdfg"></a></li>'; 
        theList.append(content); 
    } 
    theList.listview('refresh'); 
});
```

Comment: I didn't get this done because in a loop the refresh doesn't work well.

Comment: so then just do it after the loop: theList.listview('refresh');

Comment: I did the refresh after the loop, but I get the view but the links doesn't work.

Comment: did you change the anchor tag to be inside of the list item tag as suggested by the other posts? <li><a href=""></a></li>

Comment: Yes, It look now like this:                jQuery(function(){     
var theList = jQuery('#someList');      
for(i=0; i<mytool_array.length; i++)     
{                    
content = '<li id="content'+i+'"><a href="dgdfg"></a></li>'; 
theList.append(content);    
}   
theList.listview('refresh');
            
        })

Comment: so looking at your example code, is 'dgdfg' a page defined in jQM? or is it a external link? also you might want to add a value for the link as well like: <a href="dgdfg">dgdfg</a> I added your code to my answer

Comment: Ok I see the problem, before my list was: <li id="content'+i+'</li>. Then I added the text for the list item with innerHTML. When I changed it to <li id="content'+i+'"><a href="dfgdfg"></a></li> the innerHTML doesn't fill the list item anymore. Do you how I can do this?